# Citing data from other source in R package

Tags: r, package, roxygen2, citations

My R package (https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet) includes functions that lookup information in dictionaries developed by other scholars.

I've repackaged these dictionaries as data.frames and put them in `sysdata.rda` so they are available to the functions.

I've cited the sources for these dictionaries in the `DESCRIPTION` file, in the `README.md` file, and in the function documentation using the [`@reference`](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/docs.html) tag.

**Is there more that I could/should do to ensure proper credit?**

Comment: `citation('ggplot2')` will usually tell you how the package author would like the package cited. If they didn't include it, screw 'em!

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preference, but it might be better to put the dictionaries as objects which are exported, i.e., as their own `.rda` files and not in `sysdata.rda` which hides objects from the user. That way users can inspect them (for instance with `syuzhet::bing_dictionary`, and you can also document them individually with citations in, for instance, `?bing_dictionary`. But I think that what you have done is perfectly acceptable.